# Disable only one item in QTreeWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget

I have a QTreeWidget that can have many rows but only 3 columns:

[image]

In the picture I have selected my last column. What I would like to do, is to disable the last column for every item in the tree UNLESS it is selected. So in my situation only the `pidtest.xml` item would have enabled checkbox. How can I do this with existing methods?

Comment: You might try to use `QTableWidgetItem::setFlags()` function and remove `Qt::ItemIsEnabled` flag from non selected items.

Comment: ¿And how you would set them to enabled again? Just curiosity.

Comment: Exacly, If I disable whole row I wont be able to turn then on again. I only need to disable last item in the row.

Comment: `QTreeWidgetItem` doesn't support partial disabling. Try to use `QTreeView` with `QStandardItemModel`.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a complete working example on how to do that.

As Pavel Strakhov have pointed out, the example use a [QTreeView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html), since [QTreeWidgetItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitem.html) do not support "partial disabling".

In the example a TreeView is displayed, showing 2 columns (name, enabled). You will be able to edit the first column only if the second is true.

> *There is no implementation in the example for changing the values, you will have to add the `setData` function to the model to do that.*

**Complete example:**

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QTreeView>
#include <QAbstractTableModel>
#include <QString>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QList>

typedef struct entry_{
    entry_(const QString &n, bool e) : name(n), enabled(e) {}
    QString name; bool enabled;
} table_entry_t;

class SimpleModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
public:
    SimpleModel(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QAbstractTableModel(parent)
    {
        m_entries = {
            {"Jhon Doe", false},
            {"Jhon Doe Jr.", true}
        };
    }

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const {
        switch (role) {
        case Qt::DisplayRole:
            table_entry_t entry = m_entries[index.row()];
            if (index.column() == 0)
                return QVariant(entry.name);
            if (index.column() == 1)
                return QVariant(entry.enabled);
        }
        return QVariant();
    }

    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const {
        Qt::ItemFlags flags = QAbstractTableModel::flags(index);
        if (!m_entries[index.row()].enabled && index.column() == 0)
            flags ^ Qt::ItemIsEnabled;
        else
            flags |= Qt::ItemIsEditable;
        return flags;
    }

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent /* = QModelIndex() */) const {Q_UNUSED(parent); return static_cast<int>(m_entries.size());}
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent /* = QModelIndex() */) const {Q_UNUSED(parent); return 2; }

private:
    QList<table_entry_t> m_entries;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTreeView tree;
    SimpleModel *model = new SimpleModel();
    tree.setModel(model);
    tree.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```